# how to search multi hop triplets from freebase via sparql effectively

Tags: sparql, freebase

I'm now retrieving multi hop triplets from freebase via sparql, I would like to start from one mid and retrieve 2 hops away from the mid. So usually, I do things like

```
PREFIX ns:<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?out WHERE {
?x0 ?y1 ?x1.
?x1 ?y2 ?x2.
?x2 ns:type.object.name ?name2.
FILTER(?x0 != ?x2).
FILTER(regex(str(?x2), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.") && regex(str(?x1), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.")).
VALUES ?x0 {ns:m.02qmnw}.
BIND(
CONCAT(str(?x0),'\t',str(?y1),'\t',str(?y2),'\t',str(?x2))) AS ?out)
}
```

This will return me the two hop relations chain in freebase stating with m.02qmnw. And the object (?x2) is not a CVT (CVT is just something virtual to connect n-ary relations), because CVT in freebase usually doesn't have property "type.object.name".

But when I want to retrieve four hop triplets from freebase, and I give constraints that 1. the objects of first (?x1) and third triplets (?x4) should be CVT. 2. the object of last triplets (?x2) should not be CVT. Therefore, I have sparql as follows

```
PREFIX ns:<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?out WHERE {
{
?x0 ?y1 ?x1.
?x1 ?y3 ?x3.
?x3 ?y4 ?x4.
?x4 ?y2 ?x2.
?x2 ns:type.object.name ?name2.
?x3 ns:type.object.name ?name3
OPTIONAL{?x1 ns:type.object.name ?name1}
OPTIONAL{?x4 ns:type.object.name ?name4}
FILTER(?x0 != ?x2).
FILTER(?y1 != ?y3).
FILTER(?y4 != ?y2)
FILTER(!BOUND(?name1) && !BOUND(?name4) && regex(str(?x2), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.") && regex(str(?x1), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.") && regex(str(?x3), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.") && regex(str(?x4), "ns/m\\.|ns/g\\.")).
}
VALUES ?x0 {ns:m.02qmnw}.
BIND(
CONCAT(str(?x0),'\t',str(?y1),'\t',str(?y3),'\t',str(?y4),'\t',str(?y2),'\t',str(?x2)) AS ?out)
}
```

However, this is inefficient and always returns "time out". So anyone have suggestions to implement it efficiently? I'm new to sparql and I have straggled for this problem for several days? And also I think my sparql command is very tedious.

Can anybody help me? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: that query will never scale, it's simply impossible. a bunch of joins, no selective patterns, REGEX scans, etc. And SPARQL is not a graph traversal engine

Comment: many thanks for your quick reply! I see, maybe I need to give up such long hops or try to add more constraints to the query. And you mentioned graph traversal engine, do you know any graph traversal engine that may help me solve such problem? Thanks again!